# How to override coo matrix (scipy sparse) with values from a dataframe (pandas)

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse coo matrix built in python using the scipy library. An example data set looks something like this:

```
  (100981, 0)   0.015
  (100982, 0)   0.016
  (100983, 0)   0.016
  (100981, 1)   0.023
  (100982, 1)   0.024
  (100983, 1)   0.025
  (100981, 2)   0.019
  (100982, 2)   0.018
  (100983, 2)   0.017
```

I have pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
   site_0   site_1   site_2    site
0  0.0140  0.02313  0.01020  100981
1  0.0130  0.02200  0.01370  100982
2  0.0162  0.02510  0.01479  100983
```

I have written a pandas `apply` method statement (see below) to override the values in the matrix according to the "site" column value. However I am struggling how on how to use numpy vectorization instead of the apply statement.

```
# where v_coo is my matrix defined above
# where df is my dataframe defined above
def override_sites(row):
    v_coo[row['site'], 0] = row['site_0']
    v_coo[row['site'], 1] = row['site_1']
    v_coo[row['site'], 2] = row['site_2']
    return v_coo
df.apply(override_sites, axis=1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a `coo` format matrix?  That format does not implement indexing.  Typically `coo` values are set during construction, with values in the `data, row, col` arrays.  Other sparse formats allow indexed assignment, with `lil` being the best.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, the matrix is created with data, row, col, but then `tocsc()` method is called on it, I use `sparse.coo_matrix`